# Reverse Engineer Fails EF Core Power Tools

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found:
>   'Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddHandlebarsScaffolding(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection,
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.ReverseEngineerOptions,
>   System.ValueTuple2>[])'.
>   at
>   ReverseEngineer20.EfCoreReverseEngineer.GenerateFiles(ReverseEngineerOptions
>   reverseEngineerOptions) at
>   EFCorePowerTools.Handlers.ReverseEngineerHandler.d__2.MoveNext() in
>   C:\projects\efcorepowertools\src\GUI\EFCorePowerTools\Handlers\ReverseEngineerHandler.cs:line
>   154

**Database engine:** (SQL Server)

**Visual Studio version:** (e.g. Visual Studio 2017 15.7.5)

**EF Core Powe Tools version:** 1.0.604.0

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in the latest daily build, download instructions here: https://github.com/ErikEJ/EFCorePowerTools#downloadsbuilds